# Windsor Ioc container: How to register that certain constructors take different implementation of an interface

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have lots of classes that take an IMyService as a constructor argument.

e.g.

```
ClassA(IMyservice myservice)
// this should take a Concrete1 for IMyService

ClassB(IMyservice myservice)
// this should take a Concrete2 for IMyService
```

How do I do my registration so that ClassB gets a Concrete2 and ClassA gets a Concrete1?

Plus, is there a way to make one the default and only specify the instances that deviate from the default? (As the majority will take a Concrete1 and only a small number will take a Concrete2.)

I am using the fluent interface, *NOT* the XML configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Service Overrides:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<Concrete1>().Named("C1"),
    Component.For<IMyService>().ImplementedBy<Concrete2>().Named("C2"),
    Component.For<ClassA>().ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("service").Eq("C1")),
    Component.For<ClassB>().ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("service").Eq("C2"))
);
```

Comment: is there a way to have a default and just override the exceptions. As otherwis I would need to do about 100 specific registration for concrete1 and about 3 for concrete2 - thanks

Comment: When a component needs an "IMyService", I think Windsor will always return the first one registered.  So you could probably skip the ServiceOverride for the ClassA (and the other 100 cases) and just use it on the 3 fringe cases.

Comment: what are C1 nd C2 in this case? are they arbitary names given to the registrations so that you can refer to them in the serviceOverrides? or do they correspond to actual classes in my project? thanks again

Comment: The former: just arbitrary names used to identify the different implementations in the Service Overrides.